# How to show distinct based on 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have an issue where the results are showing the distinct value based on the concat of all the columns selected instead of the id, see the example below

```
select count (distinct id), 
date, 
hour, 
user

from table

group by 2,3,4
order by 2,3,4
```

```
id  date        hour    user
A   2022-01-14  5   Alex
A   2022-01-14  6   Kenny
B   2022-01-14  3   Alex
B   2022-01-14  7   Alex
C   2022-01-14  3   Alex
D   2022-01-14  5   Kenny
D   2022-01-14  5   Alex
A   2022-01-15  2   Kenny
B   2022-01-15  3   Kenny
```

my intended output

1. show only 1 ID in the result (no duplicate here)
2. show the earliest entry, eg. 2022-01-14, earliest hour
3. show the user that is attached to the earliest entry

```
id  date        hour    user
A   2022-01-14  5   Alex
B   2022-01-14  3   Alex
C   2022-01-14  3   Alex
D   2022-01-14  5   Kenny
```

Comment: Can you add a few 2022-01-15 rows to your sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Can  you update your question with exactly the logic you want?   It seems you want to group by id and show certain values for each id.  Maybe the first row for each id ordered by date and hour?

Comment: @jarlh added, but expected outcome is the same, I just want to get the first event that happen for each ID

using redash

Comment: Redash, but connected to _which_ dbms?

Comment: @jarlh connected to mysql

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the current version of MySql you can simply user *row_number*:

```
select id, date, hour, user
from (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by id order by date, hour) rn
    from t
)t
where rn=1
```